# ZeroMQ socket.recv() raised a STACK_OVERFLOW exception

Tags: c++, windows, zeromq

if use this code **in `.dll`,** a call to a **`socket.recv()`** raised an exception `STACK_OVERFLOW`, but when this code compiled **as `.exe`** it works.

**Why?**

I run a `.dll`-test by "`C:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe myDll.dll StartUp`"

```
void StartUp()
{
zmq::context_t context(1);
zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_REP);

socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:3456");
zmq::message_t msgIN, msgOUT("test", 4);
while (true){


    socket.recv(&msgIN);

    socket.send(msgOUT);
};
}
```

callstack :

```
libzmq-v120-mt-gd-4_2_2.dll!zmq::mailbox_t::recv(zmq::command_t * cmd_=0x0231f700, int timeout_=0x00000000) 

libzmq-v120-mt-gd-4_2_2.dll!zmq::io_thread_t::in_event() 

libzmq-v120-mt-gd-4_2_2.dll!zmq::select_t::loop() 

libzmq-v120-mt-gd-4_2_2.dll!zmq::select_t::worker_routine(void * arg_=0x002f1778) 
libzmq-v120-mt-gd-4_2_2.dll!thread_routine(void * arg_=0x002f17c0)
```

main thread callstack:

```
libzmq-v120-mt-gd-4_2_2.dll!zmq::signaler_t::wait(int timeout_=0xffffffff)
libzmq-v120-mt-gd-4_2_2.dll!zmq::mailbox_t::recv(zmq::command_t * cmd_=0x0019f3c0, int timeout_=0xffffffff) 
libzmq-v120-mt-gd-4_2_2.dll!zmq::socket_base_t::process_commands(int timeout_, bool throttle_)
libzmq-v120-mt-gd-4_2_2.dll!zmq::socket_base_t::recv(zmq::msg_t * msg_=0x0019f628, int flags_=0x00000000)
libzmq-v120-mt-gd-4_2_2.dll!s_recvmsg(zmq::socket_base_t * s_=0x006f6c70, zmq_msg_t * msg_=0x0019f628, int flags_=0x00000000) 
libzmq-v120-mt-gd-4_2_2.dll!zmq_msg_recv(zmq_msg_t * msg_=0x0019f628, void * s_=0x006f6c70, int flags_=0x00000000)
mydll.dll!zmq::socket_t::recv(zmq::message_t * msg_=0x0019f628, int flags_=0x00000000)
mydll.dll!StartUp()
```

---

### Update:

this example, also crashed with the same reason. Does someone know any reasons for exception stack overflow?

```
zmq::context_t context(1);
zmq::socket_t socket(context, ZMQ_REP);

socket.bind("tcp://*:7712");

while (1){
    Sleep(10);
}
```

---

### A reverse problem-isolation MCVE:

And how did this **`myDll.dll`-test** work,
if run by `C:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe myDll.dll StartUp`? Post the screen outputs.

```
void StartUp()
{
     std::cout << "INF:: ENTRY POINT ( C:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe myDll.dll StartUp )" << std::endl;
     std::cout << "INF:: WILL SLEEP  ( C:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe myDll.dll StartUp )" << std::endl;
     Sleep( 10 );
     std::cout << "INF:: SLEPT WELL  ( C:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe myDll.dll StartUp )" << std::endl;
     std::cout << "INF:: WILL RETURN ( C:\windows\system32\rundll32.exe myDll.dll StartUp )" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: And when you look at the call stack in your debugger, what are the list of functions that are called?

Comment: i update question, add callstack

Comment: crash in internal thread zeromq lib

Comment: RunDll32 has very particular requirements for the function that you call. You'll generally get away with it. **But sometimes you'll blow the stack.** See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110909-00/?p=9683, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130104-00/?p=5643

Answer (score 0):

The reason of crash is SizeOfStackCommit value in OPTIONAL_HEADER rundll32 file. 
It too small (0xC000), i change it to 0x100000.  Now all works.

Comment: **You're not supposed to use RunDll32 to run arbitrary functions.**

Answer (score -1):

### ZeroMQ objects require certain respect to work with:

there are many features under the radar, that may go wreck havoc, as you have already seen on your screen.

Best read with due care both the ZeroMQ C++ binding reference documentation plus the original ZeroMQ API ( which is often mentioned in the C++ binding either ).

Both do emphasise to never handle `zmq::message_t` instances directly, but via using "service"-functions ( often re-wrapped as instance methods in C++ ).

```
zmq::message_t messageIN,
               messageOUT;

bool successFlag;

while (true){

             successFlag  = socket.recv( &messageIN );
     assert( successFlag && "EXC: .recv( &messageIN )" );
                        /* The zmq_recv() function shall receive a message
                           from the socket referenced by the socket argument
                           and store it in the message referenced by the msg
                           argument.
                           Any content previously stored in msg shall be
                           properly deallocated.
                           If there are no messages available on the specified
                           socket the zmq_recv() function shall block
                           until the request can be satisfied.
                           */

                       messageOUT.copy(  messageIN );

             successFlag  = socket.send(  messageOUT );
     assert( successFlag && "EXC: .send(  messageOUT )" );
                        /* The zmq_send() function shall queue the message
                           referenced by the msg argument to be sent to
                           the socket referenced by the socket argument.
                           The flags argument is a combination of the flags
                           defined { ZMQ_NOBLOCK, ZMQ_SNDMORE }

                           The zmq_msg_t structure passed to zmq_send()
                           is nullified during the call.

                           If you want to send the same message to multiple
                           sockets you have to copy it using (e.g.
                           using zmq_msg_copy() ).

                           A successful invocation of zmq_send()
                           does not indicate that the message
                           has been transmitted to the network,
                           only that it has been queued on the socket
                           and ØMQ has assumed responsibility for the message.
                           */
};
```

My suspect is a reference counting, adding more and more instances, produced by a `zmq::message_t message;` constructor in an infinite `while( true ){...}`-loop, none of which has ever met it's own fair destructor. The STACK, having a physically-limited capacity and none STACK-management care inside DLL, will fail sooner or later.

**`zmq::message_t`** instances are quite an expensive toy, so a good resources-management practices ( pre-allocation, reuse, controlled destructions ) are always welcome for professional code.

Q.E.D.

---

### Tail remarks for clarity purposes:

A bit paraphrasing Dijkstra's view on error hunting and software testing: "If I see no Error, that does not mean, there is none in the piece of code ( the less if any external functions are linked in addition to it )."

No stack allocations?

**Yes, no *visible* ones.**

ZeroMQ API puts more light into it:

> "The `zmq_msg_init_size()` function shall allocate any resources required to store a message size bytes long and initialise the message object referenced by msg to represent the newly allocated message.
>
> The implementation shall choose whether **to store message content on the stack** (small messages) or on the heap (large messages). For performance reasons `zmq_msg_init_size()` shall not clear the message data."

Many years, so far spent on using cross-platform distributed systems, based on ZeroMQ API since v.2.1+, has taught me lot on being careful on explicit resources control. The more once you did not develop your own language binding for the native API.

---

After all unsupported criticism, let's add one more citation from ZeroMQ:

This adds a view, how a proper indirect manipulation of the `message_t` content is done by the library C++ bindings itself, wrapped into trivial helper functions:

> from **`zhelpers.hpp`**:

```
//  Receive 0MQ string from socket and convert into string
static std::string
s_recv (zmq::socket_t & socket) {

    zmq::message_t message;
    socket.recv(&message);

    return std::string(static_cast<char*>(message.data()), message.size());
}

//  Convert string to 0MQ string and send to socket
static bool
s_send (zmq::socket_t & socket, const std::string & string) {

    zmq::message_t message(string.size());
    memcpy (message.data(), string.data(), string.size());

    bool rc = socket.send (message);
    return (rc);
}

//  Sends string as 0MQ string, as multipart non-terminal
static bool
s_sendmore (zmq::socket_t & socket, const std::string & string) {

    zmq::message_t message(string.size());
    memcpy (message.data(), string.data(), string.size());

    bool rc = socket.send (message, ZMQ_SNDMORE);
    return (rc);
}
```

Comment: The stack shouldn't grow in a loop. And the `message_t` objects are destructed at the end of their scope (which is the end of the loop body for OP's code).

Comment: @interjay I could understand the implicit release of visible parts of the message_t instances, once going beyond the scope ( which never actually happens ), yet there is also a hidden part -- the implementation -- which allocates additional resources upon each pass of the constructor "inside" ZeroMQ internal ( pointer-intensive, cross-referenced ) resources, which ought be always explicitly .close()-ed /  ~destructed so as to get all the underlying allocations become released too. Simply put, message_t instances are not any consumable disposable, resource management care is in due need here.

Comment: The `message_t` destructor will deallocate any resources it uses. And those resources are not stored on the stack in any case.

Comment: @interjay with all due respect, sir, ZeroMQ API explicitly warns about stack allocations.

Comment: There is no such warning in what you quoted from the docs. And when they say "store message content on the stack", it simply means that the struct has a fixed-size array member and they put data there if it fits. There isn't any allocation in that case. In fact, it's completely **impossible** for a function to allocate data in the calling function's stack.

Comment: **Sorry, there is a such explict warning.** >>> http://api.zeromq.org/master:zmq-msg-init-size The Context-instance, as such, **using a private-factory of its own IO-threads pool does allocate resources** outside of the user-code control, **expecting a fair habit of external code to** also ( at some later time ) **request an explicit calls to methods, that indicate a release** for any of a user-code side, rather high-level abstracted representations of the ZeroMQ tools, that would practically allow all deallocations of the ZeroMQ internally managed allocations to also take place.

Comment: I don't see any such warning in that link. You're just making things up. When using the C API, you obviously need to release resources that you allocated. In C++ this is done automatically in the destructor. In any case, OP said that your "solution" didn't fix his problem, further demonstrating that it's wrong.

Comment: @interjay  can you check my example, does error reproduce in dll? i use for compile visual studio 2013.

Comment: ( well, O/P has (1) moved the instantiation constructor outside of the infinite loop, and (2) the text about stack allocations is present in the man-page ( it was copied from there ) (3) O/P was offered to use original zhelper.hpp wrapper function examples, where proper C++ / C / native-API message_t handling and typecasting steps are present and can be safely re-used ).